# Can we fix this grammatical error once and for all?

Tags: bug, status-declined

Its ironic how a site as big and English-focused as this can still let this pass like its nothing. However trivial it may be, it should be fixed.

[image]

Comment: Why should it be fixed?

Comment: @MattЭллен It should be fixed because it's incorrect.

Comment: It's the "Viewed 1 times" message. The fix is, refresh the page a few times and it becomes "2 times" then "3 times" and your problem goes away.

Comment: But what benefit would fixing it bring? Fixing costs SE time and money. They will need to do a cost benefit analysis to make this change. You do not make a case for why it is important.

Comment: The state of "1 views" is so extremely transient that we don't think this is worth any CPU cycles to calculate..

Comment: However trivial it may be, this should be fixed once and for all: "Its ironic" -> "It's ironic". "its nothing" -> "it's nothing" (its = possessive, it's = "it is" or "it has").

Answer (score 5):

See [Jeff's tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/1165936105):

> Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S

Also, this: ["viewed 1 times"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is using *Views* instead of *Viewed*, which would avoid using *times* after the number.

Comment: "1 Views" is still wrong, though

Comment: "Views: 1" would be correct.