# Grammatical errors on ELU: “these many votes”

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

When you click the `close` link on a question that already has close votes to it, and then hover over the little white number in a red box (in the code, a `span` with the class `bounty-indicator-tab`), the `span`’s `title` text is:

> these many votes already exist

Now, ELU happens to be the only SE site where I have sufficient rep to access the `close` link, and the `flag` link does not indicate previous flags, so I cannot tell if this wording is common to SE as a whole, or an ELU thing.

But could it perhaps be fixed? Unlike the [“Viewed 1 times”](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1976/can-we-fix-this-grammatical-error-once-and-for-all) inconsistency, this `title` text is quite consistent in being grammatically incorrect if taken to mean the right thing, or meaning the wrong thing if taken to be grammatically correct.

It’s also rather an awkward phrasing, is it not? Can we change it to say:

> Number of votes already cast

– or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this awkward phrasing has been in there for quite a while now.

I've made the change to "number of votes already cast" - this will be out in the next build (probably rev 2014.2.4.1345).